# C Code: Pass string from one function to another function

Tags: c, function-pointers, c-strings, strlen, function-declaration

The main problem is: as soon as I send a string from one function to another, this second function doesn't really get the string as a parameter.

**In detailled**:
I have a function `void myfunc()` contains a word. This word should be send to another function, so it can count the length of it. That's what I've written so far:

```
void myfunc(int (*countlength)(char ch)){

    char word[10] = "Hello\n";

    int result = countlength(&word);

    printf("Length of word: %d\n", result);
}
```

The word is being send to this function `countlength(char* word)`:

```
int countlength(char* word) {
    int length = strlen(word);
    return length;
}
```

However the function `countlength()` can't count it's length and I don't know why...

The thing is, it works when the word is in the main function. Does anybody know why my Code doesn't work?

Comment: Either change `countlength(&word)` to `countlength(&word[0])` or `countlength(word)`

Comment: `int (*countlength)(char)` is a pointer to a function that accepts a `char`. Do you mean to write `int (*countlength)(char*)`?

Comment: why do the function myfunc has `int (*countlength)(char ch)` as a paramater ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes:

```
void myfunc(int (*countlength)(char ch)){
```

should be

```
void myfunc(int (*countlength)(char* ch)){
```

instead, as the function accepts char pointers.

Secondly,

```
int result = countlength(&word);
```

should be

```
int result = countlength(word);
```

as `word` is already a `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're passing to the function doesn't match what it's expecting.

`&word` has type `char (*)[10]`, i.e. a pointer to an array of size 10.  The function expects a `char *`, so just pass `word`.  Arrays are converted to a pointer to their first element when passed to a function, so the types will match.

Answer (score 1):

This parameter declaration of a function pointer

```
int (*countlength)(char ch)
```

does not correspond to the function declaration used as an argument for this parameter

```
int countlength(char* word)
```

So you need to declare the parameter like

```
int (*countlength)(char *ch)
```

In fact the identifier ch is redundant. You could just write

```
int (*countlength)(char *)
```

That is the declaration of the function myfunc will look like

```
void myfunc(int (*countlength)(char *));
```

You declared a character array within the function like

```
char word[10] = "Hello\n";
```

So the expression used as an argument in this call

```
countlength(&word)
```

has the type `char ( * )[10]` instead of the expected type `char *`.

There is no need to use the address of operator. The array designator used as an argument in this call

```
countlength( word )
```

is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element of the array and has the type `char *`.

This function

```
int countlength(char* word) {
    int length = strlen(word);
    return length;
}
```

does not change its argument. So it should be declared at least like

```
int countlength( const char* word) {
    int length = strlen(word);
    return length;
}
```

The used standard C string function `strlen` has the return type `size_t`. In general an object of the type `int` can be not enough large to store possible lengths of strings.

So the function should be declared like

```
size_t countlength( const char* word) {
    return strlen(word);
}
```

Thus returning to the function `myfunc` it should look like

```
void myfunc( size_t ( *countlength )( const char * ) )
{
    char word[10] = "Hello\n";

    size_t result = countlength( word );

    printf( "Length of word: %zu\n", result );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well; if you use the code like this, it's working just fine
When you declare an array, its name has a type of a pointer so here **word** has a type of char* and it's the pointer of the array's first element

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int countlength(char* word) {
    int length = strlen(word);
    return length;
}
void myfunc(){
    char word[10] = "Hello\n";
    int result = countlength(word);
    printf("Length of word: %d\n", result);
}
main(){
    myfunc();
}
```

> Length of word: 6